# nGinx - DENY everything matching a pattern with one exception

Tags: nginx

I am trying to DENY access to anything that matches a particular pattern in the root direction of my app, except I want to allow one match to go through...

So, I want to DENY all requests to .* in the root directory, but if the request is to .well-known/* I want to allow that to go through.

So, I have:

```
location ~ /\. {
  deny  all;
}
```

How would I go about allowing everything to .well-known as the exception?

Comment: Add another `location` to process those requests, for example: `location ^~ /.well-known/ {}`

Comment: I presume the order is important? Would that need to come before the deny all `location`?

Comment: The regular expression location blocks are evaluated in order, but `^~` is not a regular expression, and it takes precedence over all regular expression locations, so the order is **not important**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex negative lookahead feature (details [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)):

```
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
}
```

Or use Richard Smith's solution with the second `location` block.